# Rails: Can I see the contents of hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

Is there a way I can see the contents of a hash that is being sent in by of form or a link in rails?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your controller method, just inspect the `params` hash. For example,

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    puts params.inspect
  end
end
```

You can also view these params as part of the request using something like Chrome Developer Tools or Firebug.

Answer (score 3):

The parameters sent to the request is printed to your log file in development.

If you look at the last few hundred lines of `log/development.log` you will find something that looks roughly like:

```
Started GET "/?page=2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-01 03:05:05 -0600
Processing by ListsController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"page"=>"2"}
```

You can enhance this by inspecting the object from your controller or, as mentioned by Ben.

You can have this output to the logfile by using `Rails.logger.debug params.inspect` or output it in the response from your view by doing `<%= params.inspect %>`